# JavaFX filtering listview using multiple choiceboxes

Tags: java, listview, javafx, filter, fxml

i'm current trying to filter my FXML listview using multiple choiceboxes created through scene builder.

Well at 1st I tried to implement just the filter function into my work using a textfield instead of using a choicebox just to test if it works with my custom listview and it works.

But now i'm having trouble figuring out how to implement it with multiple choiceboxes instead of just using a textfield.

Hope someone here is able to give me some insight of how to do this and Thanks.

These are the choice boxes I have

```java
@FXML
private ChoiceBox choiceBox1;
@FXML
private ChoiceBox choiceBox2;
@FXML
private ChoiceBox choiceBox3;
@FXML
private ChoiceBox choiceBox4;
```

This is where I implement the filter

```java
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(student -> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
                if (student.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                    return true;
                } else if (student.getStatus().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
        listView.setItems(filteredData);
        listView.setCellFactory(studentListView -> new StudentListViewCell());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can bind list's predicate property with a new predicate value that is generated when the value of any `ChoiceBox` changes:

```
filteredData.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> (Predicate<Student>) student -> {
    // comparisons go here...
    String studentName = student.getName().toLowerCase();
    return choiceBox1.getValue().contains(studentName) || choiceBox2.getValue() == student.getStatus();
}, choiceBox1.valueProperty(), choiceBox2.valueProperty(), choiceBox3.valueProperty(), choiceBox4.valueProperty()));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and sorry that I forgot to mention that I'm quite new to JavaFX and I do not get what you are saying can you explain it in more detail? Thanks and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: This way, the `FilteredList`'s predicate will get updated every time a `ChoiceBox`'s value is changed. Let's say you have a `ChoiceBox` that contains all the possible statuses a student can have, when the user changes the selection of the status, the predicate of the list will be changed automatically and based on that, the data will be filtered again and your view will reflect the filtered items. It's better if you can explain what those `ChoiceBox`es represent.

Comment: So a student has a name, status which are enrolled or graduated, which year are they in 1st,2nd or 3rd and lastly what major are they in which are engineering, science and business. Each choice box represents each elements and i want to filter the list based on those 4 elements. For example, if i chose the name Alex, status enrolled, 2nd year and business major it should display only students who has those elements.

Comment: The code I wrote exactly does the thing you asked for. For example, define a Status enum that contains: ENROLLED and GRADUATED and define checkBox2 as `ChoiceBox<Status>`. This way, the code will work fine and whenever the user chooses another status from that choicebox, the view will be updated automatically.

Comment: I tried implementing the code but it is giving me syntax error though can you show me how you implement it?

Comment: @CngY They have shown you how to implement it. What is the syntax error you're getting? Note that the method signature used here is `createObjectBinding(Callable,Observable...)`.